# Wordpress Topmenu Issue

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu

Can someone help me out?
I'm having a site, builed with WordPress but it just seems to fail in the TopMenu part, thos most important part of my site.

[My website](http://www.skaapproductions.nl)
Just hold your mouse on "seizoen 2010" and find out the difference with "seizoen 2009".

Hope someone knows how to fix this issue cause it's annoying as hell!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should modify css rules for #front_menu li ul ul
For example :

```
#front_menu li ul ul {
    border-top: 1px solid #ACACAB;
    left: 100px;
}
```